# can i write css in symfony2 twig template and use it in another twig template?

Tags: twig, symfony-2.3

I want to use accelerated mobile pages in my symfony application..In my symfony application there is too much css written in mainlayout twig.I want to write some specific css in one twig template and to call that template in my actual amp page. How can i perform all this? if someone had a better way to handle this..

Comment: See inheritance of Twig files to use [`embed`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/tags/embed.html), [`block`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/tags/block.html), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mainlayout.twig` or whatever template you have, [create another one](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html) and then call:

```
{% extends 'my_template.html.twig' %}
```

Then it will only have the CSS that is in your template and whatever you add later.

Comment: Actually i am talking about accelerated mobile pages specifically, It will allow only internal page css which is wriiten in <style amp-custom> tags. The purpose is to make it as concise as possible.